# Vim - navigate between paragraphs (by blank lines)

Tags: vim

Are there built-in commands in VIM that navigate to the next/previous blank lines?

Comment: `{` and `}` is what you want.

Comment: ^ above comment more to the point for the question.

Comment: if you find they aren't stopping on what looks like blank lines its probably because they have whitespace on them.  You can remove using substitute like this: `:%s/^\s\+$//`

Comment: Try adding `set list` if `{` doesn't work for you

Answer (score 13):

Next blank line use (right curly bracket):

```
}
```

Previous blank line use (left curly bracket):

```
{
```

Type the above when in command mode

Answer (score 11):

Going to the help on navigation ([`:h navigation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#navigation)):

```
Cursor motions                                  cursor-motions navigation

These commands move the cursor position.  If the new position is off of the
screen, the screen is scrolled to show the cursor (see also 'scrolljump' and
'scrolloff' options).

1. Motions and operators        operator
2. Left-right motions           left-right-motions
3. Up-down motions              up-down-motions
4. Word motions                 word-motions
5. Text object motions          object-motions
6. Text object selection        object-select
7. Marks                        mark-motions
8. Jumps                        jump-motions
9. Various motions              various-motions
```

`Text object motions` seem to be the most likely candidate (or would `Jumps`?). Move to `object-motions` and press `<c-]>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>]</kbd>):

```
5. Text object motions                                  object-motions

                                                        (
(                       [count] sentences backward.  exclusive motion.

                                                        )
)                       [count] sentences forward.  exclusive motion.

                                                        {
{                       [count] paragraphs backward.  exclusive motion

                                                        }
}                       [count] paragraphs forward.  exclusive motion.
```

Bingo!

Comment: The Vim help text system (`:help`) is one of the best pieces of online (as in "inside-the-program") software documentation that I have come across.